# Javascript object - how to properly acces to item and sort them

Tags: javascript, list, object

I have an object in javascript which has a list of properties in it. it looks like this:

```
var PRICES = {};

PRICES["1/1"] = { "price_unit" : "0 €", "price_total": "0 €", "price_total_vat" : "0 €" };   
PRICES["6/1"] = { "price_unit" : "50,00 €", "price_total": "300,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "357,00 €" };  
PRICES["12/1"] = { "price_unit" : "40,00 €", "price_total": "480,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "571,20 €" }; 
PRICES["24/1"] = { "price_unit" : "33,00 €", "price_total": "792,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "942,48 €" };  
PRICES["1/3"] = { "price_unit" : "94,99 €", "price_total": "284,97 €", "price_total_vat" : "339,11 €" };  
PRICES["6/3"] = { "price_unit" : "47,50 €", "price_total": "855,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "1.017,45 €" }; 
PRICES["12/3"] = { "price_unit" : "38,00 €", "price_total": "1.368,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "1.627,92 €" }; 
PRICES["24/3"] = { "price_unit" : "31,35 €", "price_total": "2.257,20 €", "price_total_vat" : "2.686,07 €" }; 
PRICES["1/10"] = { "price_unit" : "90,24 €", "price_total": "902,40 €", "price_total_vat" : "1.073,86 €" };
PRICES["6/10"] = { "price_unit" : "45,12 €", "price_total": "2.707,20 €", "price_total_vat" : "3.221,57 €" };
PRICES["12/10"] = { "price_unit" : "36,10 €", "price_total": "4.332,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "5.155,08 €" };
PRICES["24/10"] = { "price_unit" : "29,78 €", "price_total": "7.147,20 €", "price_total_vat" : "8.505,17 €" }; 
PRICES["1/50"] = { "price_unit" : "85,73 €", "price_total": "4.286,50 €", "price_total_vat" : "5.100,94 €" };
PRICES["6/50"] = { "price_unit" : "42,86 €", "price_total": "12.858,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "15.301,02 €" }; 
PRICES["12/50"] = { "price_unit" : "34,29 €", "price_total": "20.574,00 €", "price_total_vat" : "24.483,06 €" };
```

I'm trying to access to the first item in each list called `price_unit` but I'm not sure how to do it. I got the keys of object via:

```
for (var key in PRICES) {
    $("ul.first").append("<li>"+ key +"</li>");
}
```

but my try for price_unit:

```
for (var key in PRICES) {
    $("ul.second").append("<li>"+ PRICES.price_unit +"</li>");
}
```

returned undefined. What is a proper way?

Also I was wondering how to sort those lists by its key first. I'm courious how to sort them so their keys would appear in list in such order as: "1/1, 1/3, 1/10, 6/1, 6/3, 6/10..." etc

You can see and edit my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vX9Va/1/

Comment: `PRICES[ key ].price_unit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var key in PRICES) {
    $("ul.second").append("<li>"+ PRICES[key].price_unit +"</li>");
}
```

Here's an example how to do the sorting: http://jsfiddle.net/2wj8L/

Comment: It's that easy? thank you... Just to figure out how to sort them in proper way... I'll accept your answer as soon as possible